# How do I dynamically change the value of variable inside of an Angularjs service from the controller?

Tags: angularjs, service, swagger, swagger-codegen

I need to be able to change the value of a variable inside an Angularjs service from a controller in the same module. The TL;DR version is below ...

I have an embedded system with a RESTful API described by a swagger file. I am accessing it via an Angularjs app. To create this app, I have used swagger-codegen to auto-generate services. This results in a service that is passed a basepath that is used inside of the service from a call to $http. The service look like this:

```
API.Client.MyApi = function($http, $httpParamSerializer, $injector) {
  /** @private {!string} */
  this.basePath_ = $injector.has('MyApiBasePath') ?
               /** @type {!string} */ ($injector.get('MyApiBasePath')) :
               'http://localhost/';

  ...

}
```

In my angular app.js file, I have the following:

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', [
])
  .service('MyApi', API.Client.MyApi)
  .value('MyApiBasePath', 'http://192.168.1.128');
```

This all works well. However, I want to be able to set the basepath (specifically, the IP address) of the device from within the application. But the service is started at the beginning and I don't know how to get the controller to be able to update the service variable basePath_.

I could rewrite the service functions to accept the basepath as a parameter, but I don't want to rewrite the services they are auto-generated by swagger-codegen.

I am open to any solution - looking for advice on what might be the best way overall to do this.

UPDATE: 5/24/2016 - somebody asked me to post the swagger code. Here is the pertinent part of one of the files including the initial service function as well as a method ...

```
API.Client.MyApi = function($http, $httpParamSerializer, $injector) {
  /** @private {!string} */
  this.basePath_ = $injector.has('MyApiBasePath') ?
                   /** @type {!string} */ ($injector.get('MyApiBasePath')) :
                   'http://localhost/';

  /** @private {!Object<string, string>} */
  this.defaultHeaders_ = $injector.has('MyApiDefaultHeaders') ?
                   /** @type {!Object<string, string>} */ (
                       $injector.get('MyApiDefaultHeaders')) :
                   {};

  /** @private {!angular.$http} */
  this.http_ = $http;

  /** @private {!Object} */
  this.httpParamSerializer_ = $injector.get('$httpParamSerializer');
}
API.Client.MyApi.$inject = ['$http', '$httpParamSerializer', '$injector'];

/**
 * Thingy Outputs
 * Returns the state of all thingys
 * @param {!angular.$http.Config=} opt_extraHttpRequestParams Extra HTTP parameters to send.
 * @return {!angular.$q.Promise<!Array<!API.Client.boolGetModel>>}
 */
API.Client.MyApi.prototype.thingyGet = function(opt_extraHttpRequestParams) {
  /** @const {string} */
  var path = this.basePath_ + '/thingys';

  /** @type {!Object} */
  var queryParameters = {};

  /** @type {!Object} */
  var headerParams = angular.extend({}, this.defaultHeaders);
  /** @type {!Object} */
  var httpRequestParams = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: path,
    json: true,


    params: queryParameters,
    headers: headerParams
  };

  if (opt_extraHttpRequestParams) {
    httpRequestParams = angular.extend(httpRequestParams, opt_extraHttpRequestParams);
  }

  return this.http_(httpRequestParams);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to edit the generated factory. 
You can assign the base path url directly from the controller to the instance of the factory generated with swagger-codegen.

The constructor that swagger-codegen generate is like this:

```
function MyService(options, cache) {
            var domain = (typeof options === 'object') ? options.domain : options;
            this.domain = typeof(domain) === 'string' ? domain : 'http://localhost:8000';
            if (this.domain.length === 0) {
                throw new Error('Domain parameter must be specified as a string.');
            }
            cache = cache || ((typeof options === 'object') ? options.cache : cache);
            this.cache = cache;
        }
```

Then in your controller you have only to instance an object with the url in the constructor's param:

```
var myServiceObj = new MyService("http://www.pizza.it/api");
```

Comment: The "prescribed" method (by the swagger examples) I described above (with the .service/.value as part of the angular module declaration. When I attempt what you recommend - var myserviceobj = new API.Client.MyApi, I get:
"API.Client.MyApi is not a constructor."

Comment: Can you post here all the file generated by swagger-codegen please?

Comment: I edited the code above to show the swagger-codegen file.